# GCC throws init-list-lifetime warning on potentially valid code?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer

I'm running on Debian unstable with GCC 9.3.0.

There was a recent change on a project I work on that introduced code similar to what's below.

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

std::map<int, std::vector<int>> ex = []{
    /* for reused lists */
    std::initializer_list<int> module_options;

    return (decltype(ex)) {
        {1, module_options = {
            1, 2, 3
        }},
        {2, module_options},
    };
}();
```

The idea is that identical subsections of the initializer lists are first declared at the top, defined and assigned to the `std:initializer_list` variable at the first usage, then used in multiple places. This is convenient, and some may argue more readable, which is why it was accepted.

All was well until a few days ago where GCC started throwing a `init-list-lifetime` warning on the code. We use `-Werror` in our regression, so this fails the regression for me. I also tried compiling with clang 9.0.1, which does not throw the warning.

```
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:12:9: warning: assignment from temporary 'initializer_list' does not extend the lifetime of the underlying array [-Winit-list-lifetime]
   12 |         }},
      |         ^
```

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of the original initializer list object has ended. The storage for std::initializer_list is unspecified (i.e. it could be automatic, temporary, or static read-only memory, depending on the situation).

So my understanding is that the common initializer list value, being defined within the scope of an encompassing initializer list, has a lifetime that ends with the enclosing initializer list. From the cppreference page earlier, it mentions that `std::initializer_list` is a "lightweight proxy-object", which implies that it does not take ownership of the temporary object or extend it's lifetime. This means that the underlying array is not guaranteed to exist in later usage, which is why the warning is being thrown. Is this analysis correct?

I can prevent the warning from occuring by moving the `std::initializer_list` variable initialization to the declaration. For full details on the problem as it stands in the project see the [PR](https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/pull/1975/files).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Added a minimal example to the question, you can see it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YY4Gvf).

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is just not designed to stick around. Using an `std::vector` instead would avoid these concerns. Your MCVE makes it seem like the initialization data is constant. In that case, you can use a `constexpr` array which will help the compiler generate the best code it can.

Comment: I'm also not sure if the order of evaluation for elements in an initializer list is defined. You should define the value of your data outside of the large initializer list. Even if the order is well defined and your approach works, it is needlessly trying to pack too much work into too few lines. It is needlessly hard to reason about this code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux [The order of evaluation is left-to-right in an initializer list.](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#4).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So your recommendation is to lift the common declaration above the initializer list declaration and use either `std::vector` or a `constexpr int[]` to hold the values? That's similar to what the linked PR does.

Comment: But what I'm really looking for is a proper explanation of why this is invalid. I offered my understanding of why it is invalid, but I'm not sure if it's right, I'm not a C++ expert.

Comment: In your minimal example it looks to me like perhaps the warning is that on the line after the return statement, `module_options` holds a dangling pointer to the now-freed initializer list. So perhaps the warning is overzealous, and GCC ought to detect that nothing is assuming the lifetime is extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my understanding is that the common initializer list value, being defined within the scope of an encompassing initializer list, has a lifetime that ends with the enclosing initializer list

You're talking about the object created by the prvalue expression `{1, 2, 3}`, right?

There's an example in [decl.init.list/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#6),

> The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object ([[class.temporary](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary)]), except that initializing an `initializer_­list` object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary. [*Example:*

```
// ...
std::initializer_list<int> i3 = { 1, 2, 3 };
// ...
```

of which the standard (or draft) says

> For `i3`, the `initializer_­list` object is a variable, so the array persists for the lifetime of the variable.

This suggests the object must be materialized and should have its lifetime extended.

However, you are *not* initializing the `initializer_list` object from the expression, because your variable is already initialized. If we rewrote your code as a call to a notional

```
module_options.operator=({1, 2, 3})
```

then we wouldn't expect the temporary lifetime to be extended past the end of the function call.

I had suspected the temporary would still live to the end of the full-expression, since I thought that binding a reference to was supposed to **extend** its lifetime rather than reduce it: but admittedly [class.temporary/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6) says *"... persists for the lifetime of the reference ..."* and not *"... persists for **at least** the lifetime ..."*

However, it does mean that the following variation of your original code should do what you want:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> ex = []{
    /* for reused lists */
    std::initializer_list<int> module_options { 1, 2, 3 };

    return (decltype(ex)) {
        {1, module_options},
        {2, module_options},
    };
}();
```

Comment: _"we wouldn't expect the temporary lifetime to be extended past the end of the function call.

I had suspected the temporary would still live to the end of the full-expression"_ - don't _all_ temporaries have a lifetime that is guaranteed to match the lifetime of their full enclosing expression? This would make the first sentence I quote false.