# Why does the initialization of an std::initializer_list seem to fail in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, initializer-list

The following piece of code fails on Visual Studio 2019 compiled in Release mode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>

int main( int, char** )
{
    std::initializer_list<int> v = {};
    std::initializer_list<int> i = { 1, 2, 3 };

    v = i;
    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The second initialization of v seems to fail and the output is like:

```
1 2 3
17824704 10753212 0
```

But when building in Debug mode or building with other compilers (gcc, clang). The output is as expected:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to be clear, the only *initialisation* of `v` takes place in the line:

```
std::initializer_list<int> v = {};
```

The other two are assignments rather than initialisation:

```
v = i;
v = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

And it's the difference between those two assignments that provides the solution.

Copying an initialiser list does *not* necessarily copy the underlying elements - initialiser lists are usually a lightweight thing, and are frequently implemented as just a pointer and length.

So when you assign, `i` to `v`, the underlying array of `i` (and therefore `v`) continues to exist until going out of scope at the end of `main`. No problems there.

When you copy `{1, 2, 3}` to `v`, the underlying array *also* continues to exist until it goes out of scope. Unfortunately, that happens as soon as the assignment finishes, meaning that using the elements of `v` will be problematic after that point.

Though `v` most likely will still has a pointer and length, the thing that the pointer *points to* has gone out of scope, and that memory may well have been reused for something else.

---

The relevant text in the standard (`C++20 [dcl.init.list] /6`) states, when talking about initialiser lists:

> The [underlying] array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object, except that initializing an `initializer_list` object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary.

Since what you're doing *isn't* initialisation, this lifetime extension does not occur.

That means the destruction of the underlying array is covered by `C++20 [class.temporary] /4`:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

---

Interestingly, the [cplusplus.com site for initializer_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/initializer_list/) currently has buggy code on it with this *exact* problem (I've raised the issue with them, not sure when, or even if, they'll fix it):

```
// initializer_list example
#include <iostream>          // std::cout
#include <initializer_list>  // std::initializer_list

int main ()
{
    std::initializer_list<int> mylist;
    mylist = { 10, 20, 30 };
    std::cout << "mylist contains:";
    for (int x: mylist) std::cout << ' ' << x;
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

While that may work in some scenarios, it's by no means guaranteed and, in fact, `gcc 10.2` (checked on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)) rightly picks it up as problematic:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:8:25: warning: assignment from temporary 'initializer_list'
    does not extend the lifetime of the underlying array
    [-Winit-list-lifetime]
8 |   mylist = { 10, 20, 30 };
  |                         ^
```

Comment: @JoVanderSnickt The difference is that the initialization extends the lifetime of the temporary array (similarly as reference does), but assignment does not. See, for example, these related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15286450/580083 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62877374/580083. One might wonder why `std::initializer_list` even provide assignment operators.

Comment: @DanielLangr: possibly because of the situation regarding `i` in the question. Assigning a temporary `init-list` is problematic but, if you have one that will remain in scope as long as you'll be using the thing you assigned it to, then that assignment should be fine.